# Can't access openwrt access point's admin interface

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I've turned my TP-Link Archer C5 into an access point with [this guide](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/bridgedap), using openwrt. It works correctly, and I can now access the internet through the wlan of the access point.

I've set a static ip for the AP (192.168.1.2), as it said in the tutorial, but after connecting to the AP I have internet but can't reach 192.168.1.2. It just times out, with both ssh and a web browser.

So it seems it no longer has an ip address (it does have an ipv6 ip though, but I can't access it through that either). How can I access the web interface of my AP?

Comment: Have you tried an IP scan to see which ip addresses are available? Have you rebooted the device? Sometimes a device can crash, but still appear to work mostly. It allows traffic to be go through but the admin interface stops working.

Comment: @LPChip I have. I've rebooted it, and even reset to factory defaults. It seems to be a result of the configuration, and not a bug. I've checked my main router's routing table, and the AP isn't assigned an IP, just a IPV6 address..

Comment: @LPChip Is it inherent to access points to not have an ip? Do you know of anything I could change to openwrt's config to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you set the AP as a repeater, it will repeat all settings and thus not have an IP. If you just make it a regular AP, it should have an IP address.

Comment: @LPChip Hmm ok. There are several types of access point walkthroughs: I've used [bridged ap](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/bridgedap), but there's also [dumb ap](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/dumbap) and [routed ap](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/routedap). I'm guessing I would need to set it as a routed ap?

Comment: @LPChip A routed AP does seem much more fiddly (no automatic DHCP etc.). Is there a way to assign an ip to a bridged AP?

Comment: my knowledge does not go this far, hence that I didn't write an answer but a comment instead. I just knew enough to get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently the problem was that my main router uses 192.168.178.* as the space to assign ip addresses in (which isn't standard, usually it's 192.168.1.*). When I configured my AP like so:

```
gateway: 192.168.178.1
dns: 192.168.178.1
ip: 192.168.178.2
```

Where 192.168.178.1 is the ip for my router, and 192.168.178.2 is the desired ip for my AP it worked. Now I can reach the admin interface at the AP's ip when my AP is connected to the router via cable, and I'm connected to the AP over wifi.

All other settings were used from: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/bridgedap